# Symfony-Doctrine mapping cause infinity loop

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have Car object which has many CarHisto objects. I did the implementation, but something always goes wrong, because I got an infinity loop...

Here is the models:

```
class Car {
    /**
     * One Car has Many CarHistos.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CarHisto", mappedBy="Car")
     */
    private $CarHistos;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CarHistos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}

class CarHisto
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Car", inversedBy="CarHistos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="car_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $Car;

}
```

I have checked four times, I read again the [doctrine page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), the [symfony page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html) and a gist too.

But I do not see what cause infinity loop in the **manytoone** or **onetomany** mapping.

This problem occured in this code:

```
public function syncCarHistos() {
    CarList = $this->em->getRepository(Car::class)->findAll();

    if (empty($CarList))
        $this->logger->warning('Car list is empty!');

    var_dump($CarList[0]);die;
    // other stuff...
}
```

when the var_dump is calling an infinity loop is created and what I see isnt looking so good.
I see every php file's content!

Like this:

```
["code":"Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command":private]=>
                              NULL
                              ["synopsis":"Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command":private]=>
                              array(0) {
                              }
                              ["usages":"Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command":private]=>
                              array(0) {
                              }
                              ["helperSet":"Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command":private]=>
                              object(Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet)#423 (2) {
                                ["helpers":"Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet":private]=>
                                array(4) {
                                  ["formatter"]=>
                                  object(Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\FormatterHelper)#415 (1) {
                                    ["helperSet":protected]=>
                                    *RECURSION*
                                  }
                                  ["debug_formatter"]=>
                                  object(Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DebugFormatterHelper)#414 (4) {
                                    ["colors":"Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DebugFormatterHelper":private]=>
                                    array(9) {
                                      [0]=>
                                      string(5) "black"
                                      [1]=>
                                      string(3) "red"
```

And other Symfony php file's content too in a loop.

I am sure the problem is with the `$CarHistos` property in the `Car` class.
Because when I removed that property of Car, the infinty problem did not happened again, and I can see only one Car objectum in the var_dump.

The syncCarHisto function run by a command, so I think this is why the Command Symfony classes seen in the var_dump.

```
class CarHistoSyncCommand extends Command
{
    private $CarService;

    public function __construct(CarService $CarService)
    {
        $this->CarService = $CarService;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        $this->setName('app:car-histo-sync');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln(['Car Histo Sync', '=====================']);
        $this->CarService->syncCarHisto();
        $output->writeln('Car Histo Sync - Finished.');
    }
}
```

Do you see my mistake in the mapping, or is it in somewhere else? (This infinity looping...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var_dump` itself is causing that. It's not meant to be a debugging tool for a very large reference graph / cycling references. Persisted Doctrine entities contain a lot of references, some of them may be circullar.

Try `var_dump($carList[0]->getId());` instead. Or `var_dump(count($carList));`

You can also try Symfony’s dumper which lazy loads associated objects.

And do yourself a favor and start using proper debugger. Any IDE is capable, even Notepad++. To check whether the mapping is valid use:

```
bin/console doc:sch:val
```

Comment: Also depending of your Symfony version you can use dump() in both twig and controllers but it also works in app_dev.php remove this in production because it causes crashes.

To increment you nested in debug you can use xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
in php.ini

I also suggest write a single log file

Comment: Thank you! Well, yes, debugging helpful, but I could not configure my IDE to debug a webapp in Vagrant/Docker, that is why I use this old var_dump.
So this infinity loop solved now, it seems the problem somewhere else (I had db sync problem thats why I used the var_dump)

Comment: It's a matter of proper xdebug configuration. Just stop using `var_dump`/`dump`. Ever.